# How to consolidate data in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm fairly new to working with Access/SQL, and hoping someone can help me out. I have a table set up like this:

[image]

It's number of transactions per hour per day, by a cash drawer number. I would like to consolidate this data so that I can see total number of transactions per day, still split up by cash drawer number. I can then use that to look at monthly totals also.

Can someone help me out, or point me in the right direction of how to approach this? Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to accomplish what you need with some simple SQL queries.  Google for "SQL aggregate group by" for example queries, like https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp.  You might also want to consider writing some reports: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ms_access/ms_access_reports_basics.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How I would do it:
Make a form with two input boxes. The first with a date format and the second the cash drawer number.
After that I'd make a query (you can use the wizard) that runs from the table you have and under the date I would set as criteria the date that you set on your input box [Forms]!["Your Form name"]!["The name of your input box that has the date"] and under the cash drawer number you should put the other text box from your form. Hope I helped